# Как изменить стиль через javascript?

Tags: javascript

html код

```
<li class="it grid_li __double"></li>
```

стиль

```
.gifts_ul .grid_li {
    padding: 16px 8px 8px;
    margin: 0;
    background-clip: content-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Нужно убрать padding: 16px 8px 8px; на padding: 0;
Подскажите как сделать через javascript?

пытаюсь так не получаеться

```
 document.querySelector('.gifts_ul .grid_li').style.removeProperty('padding');
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такое решение:

```
document.querySelector('.gifts_ul .grid_li').style.padding = '0';
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Оно выполняется но не сбрасываться  <img https://habrastorage.org/webt/61/bd/bf/61bdbf13d0647298018356.png

Comment: @Иван, вы хотите удалить этот стиль?

Comment: отключить в стиле элемент вот как на картинке сверху элемент padding через javascript и все

Comment: @Иван, по-моему так нельзя сделать

Comment: Ну если может можно или вспомните напишите пожалуйста пробовал так document.querySelector('.grid_li').style.removeProperty('padding') не отключается

Answer (score 1):

Если просто заменить значение с одного на другое, то

```
document.querySelector('.grid_li').style.padding = 0;
```

Comment: Тут также выполняется но не чего не изменяется может что то я не так делаю  https://habrastorage.org/webt/61/bd/bf/61bdbf13d0647298018356.png